# Cannot ping, but can connect to the internet - Windows 8

Tags: networking, windows-8, ethernet, ping, icmp

I am not able to ping google.com or any other host when connected to ethernet (request timed out), however I do have network connectivity. When I connect to Wi-Fi on the same network, I am able to ping. I also tried disabling the firewall, and that did not work, so it is not a firewall issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your Firewall is configured to block all ICMP packets, as a result you can not send ICMP echo request packets to external networks.

To resolve this issue you need to contact the network administrator and request him to disable this firewall rule.

Additionally try resetting cable modem.

Comment: `When I connect to Wi-Fi on the same network, I am able to ping.`  a firewall usually does not distiungiush between those. So it should work in both cases or in neither.

Comment: @Michael D I tried disabling the firewall altogether and nothing happened. Also, other PCs on my network are able to ping all hosts.

Comment: This is rather curious. Is there by chance another DNS entry for something using the same IP address? Or your DNS has a different IP address listed for that system? Do you have any VPN installed?

Comment: instead of ping, try a tracert. From both wifi and network and see if it will show what is going on.

Comment: @bvaughn tracert shows all *'s from ethernet, and Wi-Fi works as expected

Comment: @MichaelD No VPN, and I don't believe there are any issues with DNS and IP conflicts. I am using DHCP to obtain the IP for my PC.

Comment: Restart your router. Sometimes part of the OS hangs which causes weird glitches where one feature works while another one doesn't. Even if wifi is on the same router, it can be the solution.

Comment: @LPChip This is not possible, as I am working on a campus network.

Answer (score 0):

==> **You should verify with your Campus network administration following:**

1) Your Windows8 host Ethernet Link connects to the same Router which facilitates Wifi internet and Ethernet internet.
2) There is no MAC address based filtering on Router.

==> If your Windows8 Ethernet link directly or via Ethernet Switch connected to wireless router's Ethernet link, you should be able to get the DHCP IP address same as you receive when you connect via Wireless LAN adapter.

==> If your Windows8 host has both Wireless LAN adapter and Ethernet Adapter, **"Turn OFF"** the Wireless Adapter and Obtain automatic IP address on **Ethenet Adapter** and check IP result via command "**ipconfig /all**" and compare that result when you **"Turn ON"** Wireless Adapter. I request you to share the outputs of "ipconfig /all" on both Wireless adapter "ON" & "OFF".

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion of comparing the ipconfig output from Wireless and Ethernet showed that the obtained IPs were different for each, which allowed me to figure out that ICMP was being blocked for the network that the Ethernet IP was on.